# Redirect single page to another domain

Tags: asp.net, iis

I need to redirect couple old webpages from my IIS to a new domain in a specific order.
For instance :

> domain1/page1 to domain2/page1
>
> domain1/page2 to domain2/page3
>
> domain1/page3 to domain2/page5
>
> ...

Here's my webconfig `<system.webserver>` section:

```
<system.webServer> 
     <rewrite> 
        <rules> 
             <rule name="redirect single page" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopprocessing="true"> 
                 <match url="domain1/page1"/> 
                 <action type="redirect" url="domain2/page1" appendquerystring="false"/> 
             </rule> 
         </rules>    
     </rewrite> 
     <httpredirect enabled ="true" destination"Domain2" httpresponsestatus="permanent"/> 
</system.webServer>
```

But the redirecting is not happening it still points to the old domain pages.

Comment: enabled =""true" ? extra ".Looks like your web.config is not wellformed

Comment: That was typo, I edited it. any clue how to fix it ?

Comment: when you say "domain"  (ala domain2.com) is it truly a domain or just a virtual folder?

Comment: I fixed the xml example typo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [301 Redirect one domain to another using web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648449/301-redirect-one-domain-to-another-using-web-config)

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly the @Claus answer on the question: [301 Redirect one domain to another using web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648449/301-redirect-one-domain-to-another-using-web-config)

You can use the following code to achieve this:

```
  <system.webServer> 
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="redirect" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www.domain1.com$" />
            </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain2.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  <system.webServer>
```

This example will match all URLs unless the hostname part is exactly [www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com) - and redirect those to [www.domain2.com/whatever](http://www.domain2.com/whatever).