# 301 redirect to another domain whilst maintaining querystring

Tags: redirect, web-config

I need to add a rule to my web.config file to 301 redirect all requests to the reciprocal page on a new domain. The website is exactly the same, only the domain name is changing so:

https://www.olddomain.com should 301 redirect to https://www.newdomain.com

but I also want url's with a querystring or extension to also redirect - i.e. :

https://www.olddomain.com/blog/ should 301 redirect to https://www.newdomain.com/blog/
and
https://www.olddomain.com/3/contact/ should 301 redirect to https://www.newdomain.com/3/contact/
and
https://www.olddomain.com/blog/?yr=2023 should 301 redirect to https://www.newdomain.com/blog/?yr=2023

I found this example in Stack Overflow [301 Redirect one domain to another using web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648449/301-redirect-one-domain-to-another-using-web-config)

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="redirect" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" />
        </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

...and whilst that 301 redirects all url's with a querystring (and maintains the querystring/extension) it doesn't 301 redirect the home page or any page without a querystring - that just redirects those pages as a 200 response.

What would I need to change to make it 301 redirect pages with and with querystrings to another site?

Many thanks.